# Quickfix file log factory

Tags: logging, quickfix

When using the QuickFix dll and the QuickFix interface, I am creating a new session using a QuiCkFix File Store Factory and a Log Factory. Is there a method or a process I can follow to clear these log files at a point in time?

I have tried the following but doesn't seem to work:

```
DirectCast(QFInterface.LogFactory, QuickFix.Log).Clear()
```

Answer (score 0):

LogFactory and Log have no inheritance relationship so DirectCast will not work. Just call clear on the Log instance.